# How do I pronounce "TikZ"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have heard people pronounce the name of the package "TikZ" in many different ways: "tiks" or "tikz" or "tik-zee" or even "tee-eye-kay-zee".  Does anyone know the authoritatively correct pronunciation?

Answer (score 17):

According to the documentation, TikZ is a recursive acronym of the German phrase "TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm." If a German speaker pronounced it as a word rather than the single letters, it would sound like English "tics". The terminating "Z" would sound like "s" as in the aforementioned "tics" rather than like "tz" as in "quartz" in order to avoid the piling up of the three consonants "ktz".

Comment: Note, this is only a guess. In German it /could/ as well be pronounced as "tiktz", which sounds like the question "Tickt's?" (= "Tickt es?" = "Does it tick?" in English).

Comment: I'd guess in German it would be pronounced as you suggest in the comment above (and note the "i" is not pronounced the same in German as in English).  Also, the standard pronunciation of "quartz" is with a terminating "s" sound, not a "z" sound.

Comment: @MarkMeckes. I know. That is why a used "quartz" as an example. It is the difference between the both possible endings "s" and "ts" I wanted to emphasize.